# What set of properties does a matrix have to have in order for all its pairs of distinct eigenvectors $x$ and $y$ to have $x^Ty=0?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, covariance

I've often seen this property used when dealing with covariance matrices, which have just have every desirable property imaginable (e.g. they are symmetric, contain only real numbers, and are positive semi-definite), but I don't recall every seeing any use of this property outside of this context. Is it just a useful property of covariance matrices? Or is it a result of some of their non-unique properties, and if so, which properties?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't formulate your question correctly (there is no matrix as in the question, simple exercise: let $y$ be a multiple of $x$).

On the other hand, trying to understand what is your real question you might want to consider **normal operators**: note that there is always a basis formed by orthogonal eigenvectors (so you have an equivalence to the property that you seem to be considering).

Comment: All $1\times 1$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_2$ have the property they originally stated.

Comment: Never heard of covariance with other fields... :)

Comment: That doesn't change that the claim that there is no such matrix is false as written.

Comment: I suggest that you give your own answer.